# Let $a,b>0$ and $f(a,b)=\frac{a^3b}{(a+b)^4}$, then find maximum value of $f(a,b)$

Tags: functions, inequality

> Let $a,b>0$ and $f(a,b)=\frac{a^3b}{(a+b)^4}$, then find maximum value of $f(a,b)$

My attempt at solving the question without differentiation (I wasn't successful):

$$f(a,b)=\frac{a^3b}{(a+b)^4}=\frac{a^3b}{a^4+b^4+4a^3b+4ab^3+6a^2b^2}$$
$$f(a,b)=\frac{1}{a/b+b^3/a^3+4+4b^2/a^2+6b/a}$$

I have done this by partial derivatives and $f(a,b)$ gives the maximum value when when $a=3b$ (which is the correct answer). I am looking for another method by using inequalities, and preferably without using differentiation.

Comment: Presumably, $a,b>0,$ since $(a,b)>0$ doesn’t make sense.

Comment: Use e.g. AM-GM. Since you already know that equality occurs when $a=3b$, this gives you a hint how to apply the inequality.

Comment: Note that $f(a,b) = x/(1+x)^4$ where $x = b/a$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply AM-GM inequality to $a/3,a/3,a/3,b$ to get
$$
\frac{a/3+a/3+a/3+b}{4}\geq\sqrt[4]{(a/3)(a/3)(a/3)b}=\sqrt[4]{a^3b/27}
$$
which simplifies to
$$
\frac{(a+b)^4}{256}\geq\frac{a^3b}{27}\ ,
$$
implying a maximal value of $\frac{27}{256}$ when $a=3b$.